# unable to remove node-modules/

Tags: node.js, node-modules, uninstallation

I don't understand why this time I can't remove my folder node_modules/ from a node project that I want to delete...

usually `npm uninstall` do a great job, `npm rm` should also work, `npm prune` even for precise packages, but here I can delete nothing ?

for exemple when I run `sudo npm uninstall node_modules/` I get :

```
npm WARN server@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN server@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

up to date in 2.312s
```

Comment: Have you tried going to the root of the project and `rm -rf node_modules`?

Comment: @l.varga yes it doesn't work (I think this never works with node_modules actually ?)

Comment: Depending on how your system is set up, you might need to use `sudo`. Just make sure you are in the correct folder, or adjust the path to `node_modules` folder. For me, this always worked (admin account on a Mac), even when all other attempts to clear `node_modules` failed.

Comment: strange... it's basic, I was certain I did it, it seems I didn't because it worked great

Comment: No problem :) If the comment was helpful and solved your issue, mark it as such please.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried `rm -rf node_modules`? I use this to remove all node modules